# Is there any custom toString() method with limited characters number of returned string?

Tags: java

I have a Map which represents Json object (so Map might have nested maps), and I want to log this Map in some places but I don't want to write to the console long strings. I'm looking for some way to get something like toString() but with ability of configuring max length of returned string. 
Overriding toString() with implementation like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString().substring(0, 100);
}
```

is not an option, because super.toString() might return really long (with >1000 length) string, which undesirable will fall into heap.

So can anybody tell if there is another way exists to get limited string of the object?

Comment: This is a bad idea - I would just read the amount of the `Map` and then `toString` those bits.

Comment: Whats the point in printing that map if you don't care that much about its content?

Comment: @Tom first fields are important for troubleshooting

Comment: There are no "first fields" in a `Map`.

Comment: Like Boris said, there are no first fields, but since you may only need certains keys, then why don't you just print these without using `toString`?